# Is XFS a distributed file system or a journaling file system?

Tags: filesystems

Is XFS a distributed file system or a journaling file system?

In Wikipedia it says that XFS is a journaling file system.But in the [Berkeley](http://now.cs.berkeley.edu/Xfs/xfs.html) website they mentioned that it is a  serverless file system/Distributed file system.

Which one is true?

Answer (score 3):

XFS is the filesystem that originated from SGI and was ported to Linux, it is a journaling filesystem.

xFS looks to be a filesystem under development at Berkeley, as such you will not find it in a production operating system, at least not for a while.

The name collision is an unfortunate source of confusion.

Edit: Removed reference to Berkeley making an unfortunate choice since their project existed first.

Comment: The people at Berkeley cannot be blamed for that name given the fact they first published a white paper about xFS one year **before** XFS was first released by Silicon Graphics.